# How to create a Java Servlet for a given jQuery.ajax () call?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a file called wfd.proxy.js that contains the following lines of code :

```
if (!WFD) { var WFD = {}; };
if (!WFD.Proxy) { WFD.Proxy = {}; };

WFD.Proxy = 
{
    SERVICE_URL   : "/delegate/WFD/WFService?",
    PDF_SERVICE_URL : "/delegate/pdf-exporter?",
    DATA_TYPE     : "json", // used by jQuery
    DATA_TYPE_EXT : "ajax", // used by ExtJs
    DATA_TYPE_TXT : "text", // used for tests
    SaveWorkflow : function(code)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: WFD.Proxy.SERVICE_URL + "task=savemodel",
            data: { code : code },
            dataType : WFD.Proxy.DATA_TYPE,
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
                WFD.Proxy.OnSaveWorkflowCallback(data);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Errore di comunicazione: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

,

    WFD.Proxy.OnSaveWorkflowCallback = function(data) 
    {

        /*
            data.response
            data.message
            data.model_new_id
            data.idsNodes[i].original_id
            data.idsNodes[i].new_id
         */
    }

};
```

I have written the code that converts an xml file to JSON format. The JSON string that i get from the code I've written until now, should be passed as the code parameter of `SaveWorkflow : function(code)` .

I'm not really sure what do I have to do at this point. 
I did some searches and saw that jQuery.ajax() calls where manipulated using Java Servlets ...

Any idea how to resolve this please? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is client side code (i.e. executes in your browser). The part that's missing is the server side. Your "ajax call" is making an asynchronous connection to a web server, using this URL:

```
 /delegate/WFD/WFService?task=savemodel&code=xxxx
```

xxxx is the value of the code variable. Your javascript is expecting a text string as response from this URL.

You don't need a servlet per se to handle this. Any web server that accepts the ajax URL and returns the required data will do (e.g. PHP...)

If you need a servlet and you don't know how to build one, I think you have a lot of reading to do.
I suggest:
[https://www.google.be/search?q=my+first+servlet](https://www.google.be/search?q=my%20first%20servlet)

Comment: In fact the value of the "code" variable should be my json string I have allready built. I must use JAVA to do this. At this point building a servlet is my only alternative ?

Comment: Please re-read the answer: You don't need a servlet per se to handle this. Any web server that accepts the ajax URL and returns the required data will do (e.g. PHP...)

Comment: I must use JAVA to do this.

Comment: Ok I was confused by the question mark in your first reply. If you have specific questions on building your servlet, please ask. Otherwise I suggest you check out some tutorials on how to build a servlet.

Comment: I actually know how the structure of a servlet is. I just don't know how to pass the json string I have created untill now to the "code" variable ... Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The "code variable" is a parameter of your WFD.Proxy.SaveWorkflow function. So just pass it when calling, e.g. WFD.Proxy.SaveWorkflow(your-json-string).

Comment: Is there any way to do this dinamically? So when the JSON object is just created I pass it to the code variable ?